# How to remove the most recent post from $the_query

Tags: wp-query, loop

Apologies for a very basic question: I've been searching for hours and can't find a solution.

I have a Wordpress page that displays all posts of a particular custom type by using `WP_Query` to return all matching custom posts into `$the_query`. Then I loop through `$the_query` to display posts one by one, like so:

`while($the_query->have_posts()) : $the_query->the_post();`

My problem is, I want to EXCLUDE the newest post, and I can't figure out how to bounce it from `$the_query`. `the_post()` accepts no parameters. I can't seem to pop off a single element of `$the_query` like an array.

Is there a simple way to accomplish this?

Thanks much.

Comment: Add `'offset' => 1,` to your arguments

Comment: @PieterGoosen is right as far as a direct answer to your question but I can't help but think there is something else going. I'm betting you are running two queries when you only need one, but without more information that is a guess.

Comment: Thanks very much, @Pieter! That was just what I was missing.

Comment: @PieterGoosen Would you like to add this as an answer so it can be 'answered'? :)

Comment: @TimMalone AFAIK, A question needs only one upvoted answer to qualify as answered, it does not actually need an accepted answer ;-)

Comment: @PieterGoosen Yup I know. I'm out of votes for the day so I've marked this to come back to tomorrow to take effect to that. ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you need to skip the current post, you can make use of the `offset` parameter. The value passed will the amount of posts to skip, so in your case, you would do

```
'offset' => 1,
```

to skip the latest post.

Just a note on offset, when you add offset to any query, it breaks pagination. `WP_Query` internally uses offset to calculate pagination. If you need to page that specific query, you will need to manually calculate pagination